# Can't pass validation_data to a model with several inputs in Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I've got a model with two inputs and a single output:

```
...
model = models.Model([l_in_wv, l_in_ng], [l_out])
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=[...], sample_weight_mode="temporal")
model.fit([tokens_wv_j, tokens_ng_j], anno_onehot, validation_split=0.2  verbose=1, epochs=20, batch_size=400, sample_weight=sample_weights, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

It trains fine as long as I don't try to pass a separate dataset as `validation_data`, e.g.

```
model.fit([tokens_wv_j, tokens_ng_j], anno_onehot, validation_data=[[tokens_wv_j_val, tokens_ng_j_val], anno_j_val], verbose=1, epochs=20, batch_size=400, sample_weight=sample_weights, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

If I try to do this, the model instantly raises this error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected l_out to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (131943, 50)
```

I've tried changing the way I pass the dataset to `([tokens_wv_j_val, tokens_ng_j_val], anno_j_val)` or `((tokens_wv_j_val, tokens_ng_j_val), anno_j_val)` or even `(tokens_wv_j_val, tokens_ng_j_val, anno_j_val)` (which is obviously wrong, because in this case the third array is considered `sample_weights`) , but all options only result in a slightly different error message. Is this feature supported? The documentation on multiple-input models tells nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.... if training works, you just have to make sure that these shapes match, except for the fist dimension (batch size):

- `tokens_wv_j.shape[1:] = tokens_wv_j_val.shape[1:]`
- `tokens_ng_j.shape[1:] = tokens_ng_j_val.shape[1:]`
- `anno_onehot.shape[1:] = anno_j_val.shape[1:]`

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the issue, because all arrays have identical shapes (except for the first dimension).

Comment: Trust the error message, it doesn't lie. If they all have the same shape, then you cannot train as well. The error message is clear about either `anno_onehot` or `anno_j_val`. They both should be shaped as `(BatchSize,3)`.  --- Now, if you do need them to be `(BatchSize,50)`, then you have to modify your model (if it's the case, we should take a look at its code).

Comment: I double checked everything, and you appeared to be right. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielMöller Please let me know your thoughts on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58870350/how-to-perform-cross-validation-in-keras-functional-api-in-python. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you :)