# How to perform cross-validation in keras functional api in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, cross-validation

I want to perform cross validation on a Keras model with multiple inputs. So, I tried `KerasClassifier`. This works fine with a normal sequential model with only one input. However, when using the functional api and extending to two inputs sklearn's `cross_val_predict` does not seem to work as expected.

```
def create_model():
    input_text = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
    embedding = Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(512, ))(input_text)
    dense = Dense(256, activation='relu')(embedding)    
    input_title = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
    embedding_title = Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(512, ))(input_title)
    dense_title = Dense(256, activation='relu')(embedding_title)    
    out = Concatenate()([dense, dense_title])

    pred = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(out)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_text, input_title], outputs=pred)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Cross validation code that fails

```
keras_classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=0)
results = cross_val_predict(keras_classifier, [X1, X2], y, cv=cv, method = "predict_proba")
```

Later, I discovered that `KerasClassifier` only supports sequential models: https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/. In other words, it does not support functional api with multiple inputs.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is any other way to perform cross-validation for models that uses functional api in keras. More specifically, I want to get the prediction probability of each data instance (when it is in test slice in cross-validation) - this is what happens with `cross_val_predict`.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

EDIT: My current question is how to input multiple inputs to `StratifiedKFold.split()`. I have put `????????????` in the code. Just thinking whether it is possible to give it as `[input1, input2, input3, input4, input5]`

Suppose, I have 5 inputs as `input1`, `input2`, `input3`, `input4`, `input5`, how can I use these inputs in `StratifiedKFold.split()`

```
k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

for train_index, test_index in k_fold.split(????????????, labels):

    print("iteration", i, ":")
    print("train indices:", train_index)

    #input1
    print("train data:", input1[train_index])

    #input2
    print("train data:", input2[train_index])

    #input3
    print("train data:", input3[train_index])

    #input4
    print("train data:", input1[train_index])

    #input5
    print("train data:", input1[train_index])

    print("test indices:", test_index)
    print("test data:", X[test_index])
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/16061/77555

Comment: I do this using the stratified K fold from sklearn, then I make a loop for each fold. In each iteration, create a new model, train the new model, get the evaluation and store it. (If you save the models, at the end you can get the mean result of the four models and it will usually be a better result than each of the individual models)

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks a lot for the comment. It is really useful. In case, if you have the python code for it, please put it as an answer. I really appreciate your support. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: @DanielMöller I spent today to implement what you have suggested. Everything seems to be working, except one. I am stucked in `StratifiedKFold` as it only support one input, and one label. Since I am having multiple inputs, I am wondering how to handle this. Please let me know your thoughts. I will also update my question with more details :)

Comment: In fact, you only need the labels to do StratifiedKFold, you will get a list of indices and then you select the inputs with that list. Provided you get the `list_of_indices`, you can `train1 = x1[list_of_indices]`, `train2 = x2[list_of_indices]`, etc. (Considering your data is numpy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting point that sklearn only supports `Sequential` but looking your model I think you can have a single input since they share the embedding etc:

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(2, 512), input_shape=(2,)))
    # (2, 512)
    model.add(Flatten()) # (2*512)
    model.add(Dense(2*256, activation='relu')) # (2*256)
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

In words, you have 2 inputs of the same domain embedded the same way, so you can use a single input of size 2. Then to mimic two dense layers, you flatten and have a single Dense layer with twice the size :) This brings you to the concatenated layer from which the model is the same.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. It is very helpfu. However, I have multiple models that I have created using the functional api. In this question, I only posted one. Not sure if my remaining models could be changed to a sequential model as I have inputs in multiple layers. If you have any suggestions for using cross-validation please do let me know. I really appreciate your support. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you :)